# Java -version error when building ionic app

Tags: java, html, cordova, ionic-framework

It's my first time developing an app using ionic framework, but everytime I try to execute `$ ionic build --release android` this error always occur. What should I do?

I already have jdk1.8.0_101 version installed.

[image]

Comment: Refer https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/

Comment: What does `$ java -version` give you?

Comment: still didn't work :(

Comment: java version "1.8.0_101"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0._101-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.101-b13, mixed mode)

Comment: Looks like you have set wrong PATH variable for jdk .Add the location of the bin folder of the JDK installation for the PATH variable in System Variables

Comment: found the solution here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36352513/android-build-failed-ionic-error-code-1

thanks anyway!